# Automatic deprecated warnings for PHP methods with @deprecated annotation

Tags: php, annotations

What are possibilities to implement helper that will raise error log with level `E_DEPRECATED` (`E_USER_DEPRECATED` in fact) when class method with annotation `@deprecated` is called?

For example for the code

```
/**
 * @deprecated
 */
public function main()
{}
```

when calling the method `$obj->main()` the deprecated warning would be raised.

And yes, I know I could add a warning using code line `trigger_error()`.

Comment: I haven't understood the usage of ticks in PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks). Maybe this is what could help? Of course this would be run on development computer only.

Comment: Do you need to always check the doctags for this tag every time you call the method or you want to parse and add the trigger once? If it is the former, as @kingcrunch said, you will be f'ed. Parsing is a memory intensive operation. The latter might be feasible depending on if you can write or find a parser to do it for you.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. As I said, I want to use it on development machine only so performance is not that important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: Put `trigger_error()` at the beginning of the method.

Long: You need to reflect the class, retrieve the DocComment, parse it and extract the `@deprecated`-tag. The problem is, that you must do this on *every* method call, and even if it there exists an easy way to catch every call, it would be a huge overhead.

Comment: Still this is not transparent solution what I'm looking for.

Comment: Looks there is no answer for this so I'm marking this as the best answer.

Comment: I know, its not that cool (like for example in java). The problem is, that PHP doesn't know annotations. Everything within `/** */` are DocComments and there are some tools, which are able to parse them (and then they call it "annotation" ...). Additional its not possible to "steal" the method call (there is a name for it, I don't remember ...). But just keep in mind: You want to remove the method later anyway, so an additional line of code doesn't hurt anyone too much :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are still interested in an answer:

```
$trace = debug_backtrace();
$trace = $trace[0];
Helper::logToFile('called deprecated method '.__ FUNCTION __.' on line '.$trace['line'].' in file '.$trace['file'], 'deprecated');
```

Where the log to file method could look like:

```
$text .= "\n";
$file = fopen('log/deprecated', 'a+');
fputs($file, $text, strlen($text));
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an RFC for it, but under discussion: [#[Deprecated] Attribute](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecated_attribute). If accepted, you will be able to do this, for example:

```
#[Deprecated("use split() instead")]
function explode() {}
```

When you call it, it will emit a deprecation notice, like so:

```
Deprecated: Function explode() is deprecated, use split() instead
```

Maybe we could get this in PHP 8.2? I hope so!

Answer (score -1):

1. may be own file parser helps you...
2. deprecated mean that in next version this function will be removed from code... in this case you do not need to think about `E_DEPRECATED`

Comment: 2. doesn't make much sense. `E_DEPRACTED` and `E_USER_DEPRECATED` should inform a user, _that_ it will get removed.

Comment: Its quite important that he focus on it. 1) if he is a user of a library, he wants to be warned. 2) if he is the writer, he wants to warn his users. Deprecation is an important enough matter so he /does/ need to focus on it else the app is broken in an upgrade.de.

Answer (score -1):

[Addendum](http://code.google.com/p/addendum/) might help, it adds annotations to PHP.

Comment: The problem isn't reading annotations. Problem is to trigger the error on deprecated method call.